# sshd.service status showing code=exited, status=203/EXEC

Tags: linux, ssh

I am using Rocky Linux. Suddenly I can't seem to ssh into my system. On doing systemctl status ssh.service I found out that it is showing code=exited, status=203/EXEC. I can't figure out what went wrong. Can anyone please help me out with this?
Sorry for being a simpleton and thanks in advance

Comment: Are there any relevant messages in the system log (`journalctl -b`)?

Comment: on checking the log it is showing
sshd.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/sshd: Permission denied Failed to loacte executable /usr/sbin/sshd: permission denied

Comment: this issue started as I was trying to install and configure react. Till now could not solve. Please help.